# Issue in dealing with deployed postgres database using prisma

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have created a local postgres database using prisma and nextjs, and I was successfully able to do everything I want with creating and deleting.
Now I have a deployed database in AWS, and I was able to connect with it successfully in pgadmin and was able to manipulate with the data inside the tables, but when I tried to connect the same project code with the deployed database I got this error **nInvalid `prisma.users.findUnique()` invocation:\n\n\nAuthentication failed against database server**
For sure I did **npx prisma** generate after using **npx prisma db pull** to pull the new schema models, so I didn't miss that, but the issue wasn't there.7
If anyone of you had the same issue before or know how can be solved please need your help
I will appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: The error message suggests that the credentials you are using to connect to your database from Prisma are not correct.

Can you check if the user you are connecting with should have sufficient privileges to access the database and perform operations?

Comment: Thank you Nurul, I was already able to get all the tables inside the database using npx prisma db pull, I think if I don't have the privileges I won't be able to do that. also from pgAdmin I can do what ever I want to the tables, since I am working with deployed version of database, Do you think there is something I properly should do beside the normal steps ?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, just in case anyone encounters the same problem. The issue was with the password I used in my database, which contained special characters. This was causing the problem.

Comment: @Alex Could you reformat you question and post the solution you came up with such that it is easy to find and understand for anyone having the same problem in the future? Maybe but the precise error in the title and the steps you took to solve in an accepted answer.

Comment: Sure, I have a PostgreSQL database on AWS connected to my Next.js project, I was able to retrieve all the tables from the database using `npx prisma db pull`.
I can manage tables in pgAdmin but when I tried to login from the website using an existing email and password stored in the database, got this error:

Invalid prisma.users.findUnique() invocation:
Authentication failed against the database server.

Comment: The issue was related to the password format. The password contained special characters like `@!`, which caused problems.
This problem was Resolved by using only alphanumeric characters.

the `.env` file contains the following database URL:

DATABASE_URL="postgres://username:password@host:port/database_name"